# Have an example of gzipped attachment decoding with Python's urllib3 or requests?

Tags: python, urllib3

I just need an example ...

I have working code with both urllib3 and requests to download a page with an attached gzipped file (of XML).

I don't see how to get this attachment with either package; all I get is the HTML page but not the attached data.

Anybody have an example showing this with either package? I could also try something else if it uses connection pooling, which is what I'm after.

Thanks for any examples whatsoever!

Comment: How is the file "attached" to the HTML?

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question to answer it... though I'm assuming it's the same as the last one I answered in which I noted that you're misunderstanding what the `Content-disposition: attachment` HTTP header means.

Comment: I understand what it means; I just don't know where the "automatically decoded" data that requests is supposed to provide is stored if it's not using the suggested filename. There's nothing new in the current directory (where the script is run) and the requests.data member is the downloaded HTML, not the attached gzipped HTML.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. Please provide an example of the full HTTP request and response (including headers).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import gzip
>>>
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> response = http.request('GET', 'http://www.healthgrades.com/acupuncture-provider-profile-1.xml.gz')
>>> print gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(response.data)).read()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.healthgrades.com/provider/chris-withey-3vvnb</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-05-18T11:51:35.703Z</lastmod>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.healthgrades.com/provider/holly-tucker-3w9mm</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-05-18T11:38:53.007Z</lastmod>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </url>
[etc...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it ... dumb mistake on my part.

I missed the extra parameter I needed that was buried in the existing code that
worked with PyCurl.

Giving "https://the.url.I.needed" gave HTML with a header showing a gzipped attachment,
while adding the parameter:

"https://the.url.I.needed?the_param" gives the XML I was expecting.

Sorry for wasting your time; requests looks like a Great Thing and I'm now on to trying
connection pooling to speed up my process.